# How do I refer to an element on a modal ASP form?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, vb6, modal-dialog, document

I am writing a VB6 project which uses the InternetExplorer.Application object to log into a website. The login form is a modal ASP form.
All the elements of .Document are from the parent page. How do I get access to the elements on the modal login form which is opened when I do a .Click on the log-in button?

This is my code:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate "http://www.guestlink.co.uk"
IE.Visible = True

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

IE.Document.All.Item("ctl00_imgLogin").Click
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

With IE.Document.aspnetForm
    .getElementById("ctl00_content_txtUserName").Value = "MyName"
    ....
End With
```

VB gives "object variable not set" error because IE.Document.aspnetForm points to an element on the parent page, not the modal ASP form. How do I get .document to point to the modal form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are using is for the main page, but the log in form is inside an IFRAME. Try changing the URL (IE.navigate) to:

https://www.guestlink.co.uk/login.aspx?placeValuesBefore

Comment: Thank you so much.
A simple solution that evaded my reasearch, but has fixed my problem.
Where can I find documentation on .placeValuesBefore?